# Remove a line using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to remove a empty line in using powershell. 
Here is my Text

```
Line 1
Line 2
<Empty line>
<Empty line>
Line 3
Line 4
```

I have tried using -replace ("`n", "") but it does not work. 
Please help!

Comment: Is your text in a variable or do you read it from a file?

Comment: as `GerritGeeraerts` pointed out, the ways that this can be solved vary depending on how you get the data into PoSh. for instance, if you get it from a file with `Get-Content`, it will be an array that can be filtered _very easily_ to remove blank lines ... [*grin*]

Comment: It is a log file. I use get-content to do the data massaging

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = """
Line 1
Line 2


Line 3
Line 4
"""

$text -replace "(?m)^\s*`r`n",''
# Or
$text -replace "(?m)^\s*`n",''
```

regex explained:

```
(?m) set the multiline flag so ^ matches the beginning of each line and not just the begining of the whole string.
^ matches the beginning of a line
\s* matches any number of white spaces (could also be 0 white spaces)
`r`n matches the end of a line.
```

Why `r`n or just `n (depending on the machine or file):

```
\`r = CR (Carriage Return) → Used as a new line character in Mac OS before X
\`n = LF (Line Feed) → Used as a new line character in Unix/Mac OS X
\`r\`n = CR + LF → Used as a new line character in Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply read the file as string array and use a `Where-Object` to let pass only the lines that contain at least one non-whitespace character.

```
$text = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Thefile.log' |
        Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }
```

Now you can save this string array in `$text` back to file, join it with `[environment]::NewLine` to become a single string again, or...